# Application Insights Alerts. Set Suppress time via ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-rm-template

I would like to deploy Application Insights Alerts based on Custom Log Search with suppressing alerts set via ARM Template. There is a property `"throttlingInMin": 30,` but it doesn't seem to do anything.

This is the template:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "existingApplicationInsightsName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-16",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules",
      "name": "Alert1",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('existingApplicationInsightsName')))]": "Resource"
      },
      "properties": {
        "description": "Description1",
        "Enabled": "True",
        "source": {
          "query": "customMetrics | summarize AggregatedValue = count() by bin(timestamp, 15m),client_StateOrProvince",
          "dataSourceId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('existingApplicationInsightsName'))]",
          "queryType": "ResultCount"
        },
        "schedule": {
          "FrequencyInMinutes": 40,
          "TimeWindowInMinutes": 40
        },
        "action": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
          "Severity": "3",
          "aznsAction": {
            "actionGroup": [
              "/subscriptions/131c713e-23e2-4eec-b592-61e975f28e6b/resourceGroups/Alerts/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/Me" 
            ],
            "throttlingInMin": 30,
            "emailSubject": null,
            "customWebhookPayload": null
          },
          "trigger": {
            "ThresholdOperator": "GreaterThan",
            "Threshold": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After it is deployed successfully. Suppress Alerts checkbox is still unchecked:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `throttleConsecutiveWindowCount` to `0`, next to your `throttlingInMin` property, like below

```
 "throttlingInMin": 30,
 "throttleConsecutiveWindowCount": 0,
```

And move them under the `action` property, like below:

```
"action": {
  "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
  "Severity": "3",
  "aznsAction": {
    "actionGroup": [
      "/subscriptions/131c713e-23e2-4eec-b592-61e975f28e6b/resourceGroups/Alerts/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/Me"
    ],
    "emailSubject": null,
    "customWebhookPayload": null
  },
  "throttlingInMin": 30,
  "throttleConsecutiveWindowCount": 0,
  "trigger": {
    "ThresholdOperator": "GreaterThan",
    "Threshold": 0
  }
}
```